# Applying to a medium level position but want internship

Tags: software-industry, job-search

The company I am thinking of applying to has a job opening posted for a medium level software development position, however I do not think I am qualified for that yet. I was thinking of emailing their HR and asking them if there is any possibility to hire me as an intern, so I can get up to speed and eventually grow into the position.

Would it hurt my chances in the future if I express interest and they decline me? I still would want to work for them, since the company is quite respectable in my area, and I am interested in the work they do, but I currently do not have the skill level for the position.

Comment: From your context, I'm guessing they're not actively advertising any vacancies lower in the corporate ladder than the medium level developer one?

Comment: Correct, but from what I hear, they employ students as juniors who worked there as interns during their study time, and I'm not a student.

Comment: I may be wrong but a "medium level" software engineering position, is, an incredibly highly-paid role that (in any other line of work) would be seen as something like a product line manager.  It's pretty inconceivable you could move from intern to that.  Of course, by all means ask them if they have an internship available.  Forget about "applying" for that particular job, it's nonsensical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got nothing to lose from asking. It may actually help you in the future as you've expressed interest and are dedicated to joining this company.

If you send an email or drop a phone call (if a number is provided) and just state your interest and that you feel although you don't feel like you're qualified for the middle position you would like to see if there are any lower vacancies.

Comment: I considered that, but I fear the reply will be a no, and when I later on apply for the "real" position, they will reply that I have previously asked for an internship and that they can give me that spot, but not the position that I would be applying for.

Comment: @user88765555555 If you apply for the middle position in a year or two years time, they're not going to re-offer you the junior position if you've progressed and got more experience and developed your skills.

Answer (score 0):

Best not to apply for anything you're not going to get, just contact their HR and ask if any openings are available for someone with your skillset and experience. I got most of my jobs that weren't advertised positions doing this.